# Sticky bottom bar disappear in Google Search app for iOS?

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a problem with Google Search application for iOS. When opens a page through Google search app the bottom sticky bar disappears on scroll down and if I scroll up the sticky bar appears. The bottom sticky bar hides under the google search app bottom bar. I tried to change my sticky bar height, but with no luck - the bar always disappears under google search app bottom bar. Any ideas how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed this problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    //Check for Google Search App
    var strAppVersion = window.navigator.appVersion;
    var GSAPosition = strAppVersion.search('GSA');

    if (GSAPosition > 0) {
        var lastScroll = 0;

        $(window).scroll(function(event){

            //Sets the current scroll position
            var topOffcet = $(this).scrollTop();

            //Determines up-or-down scrolling
            if (topOffcet > lastScroll){
                //if scroll-up change .desktop-price-block bottom property
                $('body #body-container-sc #container #product-page .desktop-price-block').css({'bottom': '0'});
            }
            else {
                //if scroll-down change .desktop-price-block bottom property
                $('body #body-container-sc #container #product-page .desktop-price-block').css({'bottom': '130px'});
            }
            //Updates scroll position
            lastScroll = topOffcet;
        });
    }
});
```